# Transition in React is not working like expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, event-loop

From the website and some articles, i have learned that any changes made to the app will first be reflected in the Virtual DOM. and then to the Real DOM after diffing both trees. the lifecycle hook useEffect will fire once the Real DOM is populated.

## Problem

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {


    const ref2 = ref.current;

    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = "ASDF"
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.transition = "all 5s"


    ref2.appendChild(div);

    // this should work theoretically and my div should get a transition
    div.style.top = "100px"


  }, [])
  console.log("render")
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

Running the above code gives a static div with top as 100px instead of a transition.

So, I tried the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {


    const ref2 = ref.current;

    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = "ASDF"
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.transition = "all 5s"



    ref2.appendChild(div);
    
    // The following three lines is the only change
    setTimeout(()=>{
      div.style.top = "100px"
    }, 0)

  }, [])
  console.log("render")
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

and this gives me the result i wanted. where initially the div is positioned at the top and animates to 100px.

**Why does a 0 second setTimeout work? Does it have something to do with the event loop? **

I can't use useTransition, animations API, framer-motion or any other animation method. I need the transition to happen this way only. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent the night looking into this problem. Check out this code:

```
function tellMeWhatsPassed(thing){
   console.log(thing)
}

function createThing(){
   const div = {}
   div.innerHTML = 'original'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
   div.innerHTML = 'updated'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
}

createThing()

// {innerHTML: 'original'}
// {innerHTML: 'updated'}
```

Since JS executes sequentially we expect that since we are calling the `tellMeWhatsPassed` with two different arguments we get two different console logs.

Now watch what happens when we update the code and instead of creating an object we create a html div element.

```
function tellMeWhatsPassed(thing){
   console.log(thing)
}

function createThing(){
   const div = document.createElement('div')
   div.innerHTML = 'original'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
   div.innerHTML = 'updated'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
}

createThing()

// <div> updated </div>
// <div> updated </div>
```

We've got two things going on: the DOM API is being executed off the main stack and is reintroduced through the event loop AND there's a quirk with console logging that shows us only the latest when passing a reference compared to a primitive.

To prove this last point convert the `console.log(thing)` to `console.log(thing.innerHTML)` and you can see the latest updated `innerHTML` property. Alternatively you could pass the `div.innerHTML` to `tellMeWhatsPassed`

This isn't exactly an answer but I hope my findings at least help you!

Comment: You are completely wrong about this one. run your code with the following function, function tellMeWhatsPassed(thing){
   console.log(thing, thing.innerHTML)
}. the reason both divs are showing updated is a quirk of console.log. even in the first example, if you expand the objects, you will get innerHTML updated. try it once.

Comment: The quirk in question is this. whenever you console log a thing, it will console log a "snapshot" of it at that moment to the console. When you log an object or any other variable which has a reference assigned to it, it will simply take a snapshot "{innerHTML: original}" in this case, and log it. when you click the triangle to the left of it, it will calculate the value of it at that point, using the reference. logging a HTMLElement is the same thing too since it is a reference as well.

Comment: Check out this image, https://imgur.com/a/KKxHgqc

Answer (score 0):

You are right... It will delay the execution till the executing code must complete.
Putting some delay for witnessing UI changes is helpful.

> This is because even though setTimeout was called with a delay of zero, it's placed on a queue and scheduled to run at the next opportunity; not immediately. Currently-executing code must complete before functions on the queue are executed, thus the resulting execution order may not be as expected.

Comment: Sorry for being a year late on this, but by any chance do you remember the source for this? I would appreciate it if you could share it with me